# Why isn't there more important characters at the Council of Elrond?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

The meeting is obviously extremely important, yet there is so many minor characters there and not that many important leaders etc.

Comment: Most leaders have better things to do than take a month or two to travel halfway across the world to Rivendell.

Comment: How do you define important?

Comment: Characters with more impact on the world.

Comment: You mean to tell me, Gandalf, Elrond, Boromir, Gloin, Glorfindel, Aragorn, Bilbo and Frodo weren't important? What do *you* define as important then? Sauron himself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who called and ordered the Council of Elrond?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108937/who-called-and-ordered-the-council-of-elrond)

Comment: I believe the dupe answers this. The council wasn't one that was intentionally called, it was held because some of the "great and good" from the main kingdoms happened to be in one place.

Answer (score 5):

Elrond didn't send a bunch of invitations out.  These people were already arriving in Rivendell for various reasons on their own, and Elrond decided to take advantage of that.  He was not going to wait for the time it took to send messengers to various distant places and again wait for the people to travel to Rivendell, if they wanted to come at all.

Comment: I have a book quote to back that up if you want.